# Approximation of an Operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Suppose that $A$ is an bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space such that $\left\|A\right\| \leq 1$.  Can we approximate $A$ by an operator $\tilde{A}$ such that $\tilde{A} = \sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n R_n$ where $\alpha_j \in [-1, 1]$ and $R_n$ are mutually orthogonal projections?

I asked this question on Math Stack-exchange a few days ago but did not receive any responses.

Comment: Approximate in what topology?  And what does "mutually orthogonal" mean in a Banach space?

Comment: @NateEldredge with respect to the operator norm in a Hilbert space, corrected thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by approximate? Of course you can write $A= B +( A-B)$ and then minimize some norm of $A-B$. Is that the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the $R_n$ are *orthogonal* projections the answer is no, in general.

Since orthogonal projections on orthogonal subspaces commute, the sum $\tilde{A} = \sum_n \alpha_n R_n$ commutes with its adjoint $\sum_n \alpha_n^* R_n$. Conversely, a bounded normal operator has an orthogonal spectral deposition.